# SAP2000 API with Visual Studio 10 C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the SAP2000 COM to be imported into a visual studio 10 C++ console application project so I can use the SAP2000 API in my project. However every time I use the import rather it be with the SAP2000.exe, SAP2000.tlb, or SAP2000.dll I keep getting the error:

"Error  9   error C1084: Cannot read type library file: 'SAP2000.tlb': Error loading type library/DLL.  c:\users\jgr208\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sapapi\sapapi\sapapi.cpp  5   1   SAPapi".

Does anyone know any possible solution to import the SAP2000 COM into vs10 C++ (I have gotten it to work with C#, but I am more familiar using C++)? I have pasted the code below, sorry if it is not formatted right since I am new here.

```
// SAPapi.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

//standard header
#include "stdafx.h"
//import of SAP2000 COM (LINE WHERE ERROR ALWAYS OCCURS)
#import "SAP2000.tlb"

//empty main
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
 {
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Did you add references to that type library in your project?

Comment: That's pretty non-descript.  At least double-check with oleview.exe, File + View Typelib

Comment: TO Alexandru yes I did, or I at least tried with putting the folder in the reference path. However the SAP2000 COM never showed up in the object browser so I am not sure if I did it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First I recommend you to read examples of the CSI_OAPI_Documentation.chm (for versions before 20 the file name might be slightly different but the path is the same) file which is placed in the installation directory of the SAP2000.
I think you have not included the .tlb file into the resources of your code.